# Spring boot slf4j/log4j disable daily RollingFilePolicy

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, log4j, slf4j

My Spring boot application is creating every day a new archive (named like `logging.log.2019-08-30.0.gz`) and starts logging in a new file. What would be the way to disable this feature and let the logger log into the old file, no matter how many days passed?

I created a Spring boot application about 1.5 year ago and its loggers did not have this kind of behavior, but the one I recently created has it. *Maybe it has to do with the new versions?*

I use almost the exact same configuration, but still... new logs taking place every day. I tried a lot to find something online, but all posts talk about how to add it, and not how to remove it.

Here are all the settings related to logging in `application.properties` (I do not use any kind of extra configuration):

```
logging.level.root=INFO
logging.level.org=WARN
logging.level.com=WARN
logging.pattern.console=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %c{1} - %msg%n
logging.pattern.file=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %c - %msg%n
logging.file=logging.log
logging.file.max-size=1GB
```

The complete list of the dependencies in `pom.xml` (Latest versions to all):

```
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
thymeleaf-spring3
spring-boot-starter-security
spring-boot-starter-web
spring-boot-starter-mail
mysql-connector-java
spring-boot-configuration-processor
```

The way I create and use my loggers:

```
private static final org.slf4j.Logger log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyController.class);
...
log.info("My controller did something!");
```

Comment: Which appender are you using in logging.log? Use the FileAppender and not the RollingFileAppender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of hours of searching how to remove `RollingFilePolicy` without using `logback.xml` I gave up. So, in order to achieve it (and keep my current logging appenders), I added a `logback.xml` file in `src/main/resources` file as the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include
        resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
    <property name="LOG_FILE"
        value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}}/spring.log}" />


    <appender name="FILE"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <file>${LOG_FILE}</file>
    </appender>
    <appender name="CONSOLE"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

I created it based in spring logging defaults inside `org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/` package, ignoring `FileAppender.xml` file.

Note that as it seems in Spring's [github repository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback), default logging configuration is changing and these XML files are absent.

Comment: Can you still configure the logging via the application.properties? Basically I just want to disable the daily RollingFilePolicy and control the rest through the application.properties. But I somehow don't get it working.